# Class calling with strings

Tags: java

I might have been mis-understood, I want to create objects and specify which class the object is by using a string.

Comment: What do you mean by "class calling"?

Comment: What do you mean by "call a class"?

Comment: I think the OP needs to read up on [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).

Comment: *"I'd like to know if there's a way to call a class by specifying it's name"*  While vital for some uses, reflection is often the 'right answer to the wrong question'.  What are you actually trying to ***achieve*** by loading classes by their name?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) for that.

To get a class, use

```
// if your class is in package com.foo and is named Bar
Class<?> klass = Class.forName("com.foo.Bar");
```

Read the tutorial for more details.